# Declension of pronoun when nouns of multiple genders follow

Tags: pronoun, declension

How are adjectival pronouns declined when nouns of multiple genders follow?
For example:

***Jede/Jeden* Höcker und Kurve in der Straße.**

The nouns Höcker und Kurve are of different genders (masculine and feminine respectively) - but then, does the use of two nouns also make it a plural?
How is Jede declined in this case?

Comment: What do you mean with Höcker? A bump? A sleeping policeman?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17264/article-with-a-coordination-of-two-nouns-in-different-genders

Comment: Der Satz kein Verb. Vielleicht: "Er kannte jeden Höcker und jede Kurve in der Straße".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two of them:

> Jeder Höcker und jede Kurve in der Straße.
>   Jeder/Jede Höcker/Kurve in der Straße.

Normally, two nouns would make it plural. However, there is an exception when using *jede, keiner, mancher*. The verb that follows then requires the singular form: [See here](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mit-49575)

> Jeder Höcker und jede Kurve in dieser Straße führt dazu, dass man ständig abbremsen muss.
>   *Every bump and every turn on this read cause you to break all the time.*

Comment: Somehow, that phrase does not have an adjectival pronoun followed by *multiple nouns*, unless there's some higher order syntax underlying that is expressed in your second variant, which is not colloquial at all, only written in technical writing.

Answer (score 0):

> How are adjectival pronouns declined when nouns of multiple genders follow

Not at all! The word "alle" is used in that case, and it is not declinable for gender.

> *Alle Höcker and Kurven*.